# How to get Statistics I/O info (logical reads) for a stored procedure that uses scalar functions?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, sqlperformance

I'm troubleshooting performance issues for a stored procedures (that I didn't write). The stored procedure includes multiple scalar function calls, in the Select, Join, Where, and Order By clauses.

From what I can tell, turning on Statistics I/O and looking at logical reads, which is usually very useful, doesn't give good info here. This is because the logical reads returned must not include functions. I'm inferring this because the tables referenced in the functions don't exist in the statistics i/o output.

Are there some strategies to overcome this, and get the TOTAL logical reads of a stored procedure, including the function calls?

EDIT - using SQL Server 2017

Comment: Do the scalar functions read from tables?  Have you looked as sys.dm_exec_sessions?

Comment: Yes, many of the scalar functions read from tables. 
I just looked at logical reads on sys.dm_exec_sessions. It's giving me information that I don't like (that the simplified SQL  is still using more logical reads than the original stored procedure, with all the functions). Not sure I trust it, because when I run (with Statistics I/O turned on) the straight SQL, no functions, i get the full set of table names in the Stastics I/O output. But when I  run the stored procedure, Statistics I/O shows me a limited set of tables, skipping the tables that the functions hit.

Comment: BTW thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Statitics IO already includes the total logical reads of a stored procedure with functions inside.
Put a function in JOIN, in WHERE clause, in ORDER BY can cause performance problem because in previous versions of SQL Server the function’s cardinality estimate is 1 (before SQL 2012) and 100 (after SQL 2012 and before of SQL 2017) and the engine can generate a bad execution plan. With SQL 2017 Microsoft introduced the feature called interleaved execution in order to produce a more accurate estimate
but there are still things to improve.

I adivise you to remove functions and try to put the statements inside the stored procedures, using a CTE, temp tables, intermediate calculation steps, ecc.. if you need.

Comment: Thanks for this. When I turn on statistics io and run the sp, it does not show the logical reads for tables referenced only through the functions (SQL Server 2017). I can tell because there are tables that the functions reference (not the calling sp) that don't show up in the output.
I would love to remove all the functions. I'm in the process of testing that the "new and improved" sql is truly an improvement. Need accurate logical reads to do that.